# Images in node template

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm using drupal 7.x and am creating a node content-type template. My content type has multiple custom fields including an image field. I am attempting to add the imagefield and its attributes to the node template. I can display the image using

`print render($content['field_custom_image'][0])`

however i also want to display the filename and the title text. I tried code below but it doesn't display anything.

```
print render($content['field_custom_image'][0]['und']['title'])
```

In Drupal 6 I was able get this to work using:

```
print $node->field_custom_image[0]['data']['description']
```

My output when I execute `print_r($node)` is the following.

```
[field_reclaimer_image] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [fid] => 8 [alt] => [title] => test title [width] => 1117 [height] => 651 [uid] => 1 [filename] => 24-1033_angle_02_1339771175.jpg [uri] => public://images/24-1033_angle_02_1339771175.jpg [filemime] =>…
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like so:

`echo $node->field_custom_image['und'][0]['filename'];`

`echo $node->field_custom_image['und'][0]['title'];`

und and 0 are the wrong way round. If you wrap your `print_r()` in `<pre>` tags you'll see a much more nicely formatted array which is a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the node object, you should use [field_get_items()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7), which returns the values of a field, basing on the language the field would use, which normally is the language associated with the node. The code I would use is the following one, to print information from the first image.

```
$values = field_get_items('node', $node, $field_name);
if (!empty($values)) {
  print $values[0]['title'];
  print $values[0]['description'];
}
```

`render()` is not necessary, in this case, as you are rendering a string. What the function does, in that case, is just to return the value passed as argument.

```
function render(&$element) {
  if (is_array($element)) {
    show($element);
    return drupal_render($element);
  }
  else {
    // Safe-guard for inappropriate use of render() on flat variables: return
    // the variable as-is.
    return $element;
  }
}
```

If the value you are trying to render could be a string, or a rendering array, then it is more appropriate to use `render()`.

I tried the following code in my test site. The node I am loading contains an image field.

```
$node = node_load(8);
$values = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_image');

dsm($values);
```

What `dsm()` shows is the following.

[image: screenshot]

The returned array can contain more than one element, depending on the field settings. Be prepared to handle more than one image.

Using `field_get_items()`, you don't need to deal with the language. For some fields, the language ID could be "und" that is used for fields that have a value that don't depend from a language; for other fields, the correct value to use could be the one set for the node.

Consider also that there are modules that can alter the value associated with a field, and using "und" is not necessarily the correct thing to do, also for those fields that contained a valid value for the "und" array index.

Comment: That's just rendering the image though. I think they're after the description and title fields which I don't think you can render that way. I'm happy to be proved wrong though.

Comment: No, `field_get_items()` is not for rendering a field; it's to get its value.

Comment: How would you get the title using it?

Comment: I would use `$values[0]['title']`, to get the title of the first image.